# How to print the name of the files that contains "#!bin/bash" on the first line

Tags: linux, bash, find, line

I tried to print the name of the files that contains `#!bin/bash` on the first line (the extension doesn't matter) that are in the same file.

I did this which allow me to print the name of the files that contains : `#!bin/bash` everywhere in the file, but I only need to print the name of the files that contains this chain on the first line.

Here is what I did :

```
find . -type f -name - grep -L '#!bin/bash' {} \; -printf '%f\n'> file.txt
```

Comment: "Here's what I did..." and... what happened? `-L` excludes files with the match, you want `l` (lower case L).

Comment: You *are* aware that usually `#!bin/bash` is wrong: usually, the paths in the shebang line are absolute, so it should be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @MarcusMüller Perhaps that's why they are trying to find them?

Comment: @EtanReisner: that was my guess, too, but together with the mistakes in the find line, I thought it might be wise to verify

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah, I just reverted my changes to the command because there are too many for me to be comfortable "fixing" at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `awk` for this?

```
awk 'NR==1 && ($0 == "#!bin/bash") {print FILENAME} {exit}' file
```

This checks if the first line has this content. If so, it prints the filename. Then, no matter what happened before, it exits the file since it is not needed to process it anymore.

Using `find` to provide the files to the `awk` command, just say `find /your/path -exec awk '...' {} \;` such as:

```
find -type f -exec awk 'NR==1 && ($0 == "#!bin/bash") {print FILENAME} {exit}' {} \;
```